# How to resolve You need to use a AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity',already using descended of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I'm Gettiing the error -  'IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity, the activity is already using descended of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

[image: crashlytics page]

Already using descended of Theme.AppCompat

[image: Already using descended of Theme.AppCompat]

Any suggestion as to where should i look for an answer.